# How can I create an Arraylist of Arraylists containing objects in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to organize books in a library program. I have an abstract class that sets up a constructor for a book object. Then, 5 sub classes inherit from the abstract class to create 5 different genres. Each subclass has an arraylist, but I want another arraylist to contain the 5 arraylist so that I can categorize them. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of list : `List<List<abstractClass>>`. However, I think it would be easier with a map if really you want to categorise them. For example :

```
Map<String, List<YourAbstractClass>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
aMap.add("type1", yourListOfType1);
aMap.add("type2", yourListOfType2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always construct something like `List<List<Book>> = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Book>>();`